# Не подгружаются зависимости maven intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, junit

Пытаюсь подключить junit 5 с помощью:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
<artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
<version>5.5.2</version>
<scope>test</scope>
```

но пишет Dependency 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2' not found  и горит красным вершн. Это же касается и вебдрайверменеджера. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У меня так в идее тоже иногда бывает. Попробуйте сделать в командной строке `mvn compile`, он выкачает зависимости, потом сделайте реиморт в идее.

Comment: Хм, действительно, помогло. Спасибо.